# JQuery nested $.each() in <script> in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to hide li elements with certain ID in ul. This is my jQuery, but it is wrong and I don't know how to properly iterate through `$.each` to get correct values.

```
<script>
$(@idList).each(function (i,val) {
    var linkId = val[i];
    $("li").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("id") != linkId )
            $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

If I just use  `$("li").each(function () { if ($(this).attr("id") != 1) $(this).hide();`

It will hide all li apart from the one with id=1.
But I want to hide multiple li acording to what id's are in the list @idList;

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The code seems much more complicated than it needs to be. If `@idList` is just a selector string with multiple id values, eg. `#foo, #bar` then you can simply call `hide()` directly on that object: `$('@idList').hide()` - note the `'` wrapping the output from your server side C# code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I think he wants to hide all the ones *except* in that list.

Comment: `val[i]` doesn't make much sense. `i` is an index into the `$(@idList)` elements, `val` is a specific element. Why are you then using `i` as an index into `val`?

Comment: @Barmar I was working on this statement: 'I am trying to hide li elements with certain ID in ul', but the question is lacking in useful detail so you could well be right. If the OP did want that logic, then use `:not()`: `$('li:not("@idList")').hide();`

Comment: First, as you're asking about javascript/jquery, ensure the code you provide is the *rendered* html/js, otherwise we have to guess if `@idList` = `"id1,id2"` or `"#id1,#id2"` or even `"'#id1'"` (which seems odd, but possible) so you don't need the `'` around the server-side code.   If it's an actual `list` (as determined by the name... (always use the correct variable name)) then maybe you need to convert to a string?

Comment: Also, debug.  Look at the value of `linkId` in each iteration (maybe just with a `console.log(val, linkId)`) and you'll see it's very unlikely to be what you're expecting.

Comment: Hi guys. Sorry, my question does lack of specifics. Basically what I want to do: I have a checklist on my main page, that populates the list @idList. If id from this list matches the id of the li then i want that li to be hiden

Comment: Can you give an example of `@idList`?

Comment: @freedomm-m It is a List<string> idList{"1","2","3","5"}

Answer (score 0):

You can use **for loop** to check the list, and hide the related `<li>`, you can check more details in my demo:

```
<style>
html {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>   
<div>
<ul>
    <li id="1"><h3>First line</h3></li>
    <li id="2"><h3>Second line</h3></li>
    <li id="3"><h3>Third line</h3></li>
    <li id="4"><h3>Fourth line</h3></li>
</ul>
</div>
@section Scripts
{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.visibility = "visible"; //ensure jquery is executed before showing the view
        
        var idList = new Array(); // this part is to get the List
        var i;
        idList = ["1", "3"];    

        $("li").each(function () {
            for (i = 0; i < idList.length; i++) {
                $("#" + idList[i]).hide();  //hide the related id
            }
        });
    });                   
</script>
}
```

Then only id=2 or 4 will be showed

[image]